# How to create a signature for Instamojo's payment link in PHP?

Tags: php, instamojo

I would like to know which function I can use to create signature for Instamojo's payment links in PHP and what procedure should I follow if I had an array of read-only values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`hash_hmac`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function in PHP to create the signature. Instamojo uses "sha1" algorithm, so, your `hash_hmac` call will looks like:

```
hash_hmac("sha1", $message, $salt)
```

Here `$message` is going to be the `"|"` separated values and `$salt` will be private salt from the [developers page](https://www.instamojo.com/developers/)(make sure you are logged in).

**The algorithm for generating `$message` is:**

Arrange the **read-only** fields in the alphabetical order of their keys. If you have any keys with upper-case letters, **convert them to lower-case** letters first.

Let's say the url is:

> https://www.instamojo.com/demo/demo-offer/?data_name=Aditya+Sengupta&data_email=aditya@instamojo.com&data_phone=9999999999&data_amount=123.45&data_readonly=data_name&data_readonly=data_email&data_readonly=data_phone&data_readonly=data_amount

For the above url you would get the following order:

1. `data_amount`
2. `data_email`
3. `data_name`
4. `data_phone`

Using the above order of keys we will get the values in following order:

1. 123.45
2. aditya@instamojo.com
3. Aditya Sengupta
4. 9999999999

Now concatenate the above values using `|`(pipe) operator, so `$message` will look like:

```
123.45|aditya@instamojo.com|Aditya Sengupta|9999999999
```

If your `$salt` is "abcde" then you will get this as signature:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $message = "123.45|aditya@instamojo.com|Aditya Sengupta|9999999999";
php > $salt = "abcde";
php > echo hash_hmac("sha1", $message, $salt) . "\n";
676a4b5ba30e464f027249747a63ea587f8c4b9a
```

---

**How to do this if I had an array of read-only values**?

Well you need to sort the array by keys first, it should be case-insensive. If you're using PHP **5.4.0 +** you can do something like this:

```
php > $read_only_fields = ["data_email" => "aditya@instamojo.com", "data_Phone" => "9999999999", "data_name" => "Aditya Sengupta", "data_Amount" => "123.45"];
php > ksort($read_only_fields, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
php > $message = implode('|', $read_only_fields);
php > echo $message . "\n";
123.45|aditya@instamojo.com|Aditya Sengupta|9999999999
php > $salt = "abcde";
php > echo hash_hmac("sha1", $message, $salt) . "\n";
676a4b5ba30e464f027249747a63ea587f8c4b9a
```

For older versions of PHP(older than 5.4.0) use this for sorting:

```
uksort($data, 'strcasecmp');
```

---

For more info read their [Integration documentation](https://www.instamojo.com/instamojo/integration-documentation/?intent=buy) and [How do I ensure that the link is tamper proof?](http://support.instamojo.com/support/articles/202176-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-link-is-tamper-proof-).